# cascade_callbacks not working for embedded doc in mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid, cascade

I'm using Mongoid, and I have one class (Order) that "embeds_many" of another class (LineItem). Specifically, in Order, I have:

```
embeds_many :line_items, cascade_callbacks: true
```

And in LineItem, I have:

```
embedded_in :order
```

Everything works as it should except for the cascading_callbacks. When I make a change to an Order object and call "save", I would expect the "after_save" callbacks on all of the embedded LineItem objects to be called. This is not happening. I thought that was the point of cascading_callbacks.

Am I incorrect? Is something else required to make the save-related callbacks fire for each embedded document when the parent is saved and cascade_callbacks is set to true in the relationship?

Answer (score 3):

I think, when you specify **cascade callbacks: true** in the parent document, the callbacks of the embedded documents are fired only when you make any change in the corresponding embedded document. 
To check, change something in the embedded document and save the parent document. In this case I think the callbacks will be fired

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior I saw prior to creating this question. But that's the whole point. The Mongoid docs are written in such a way that they appear to claim that all callbacks will be fired when the parent doc is saved. This, however, does not seem to be the case. And my question is, "Is there a way to make that happen?", because that's the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: This gets me every time! Can call `touch` on the embedded doc to force a re-save, e.g. `@order.line_items.first.touch`